# Android IMU accuracy

Tags: android, accelerometer, smartphone, gyroscope, magnetometer

I'm working on a project with the goal of tracks animals from a hill. In the first field season we used using OpenTags and a calibrated camera, which worked but required extensive processing/calibration and-crucially-did not provide any visual feedback when the system went awry.

Since one of the goals of the project is to make it easy for other biologists to repeat,I'm investigating using the gyro, magnetometer, and accelerometer already in smartphones. Then, using an app or some simple post processing transfer this to roll, pitch, and yaw.

My question is regarding the accuracy of the smartphone vs an OpenTag. In order to track animals at distances greater than 200m, the system must have sub-degree accuracy and, more importantly, low noise. I've been looking at the Sensor Kinetics app but I find that the pitch/yaw/ heading values tend to drift more than is acceptable. I'm not sure if this is a filtering issue or an issue with the sensors themselves.

Does anybody know where I might find this type of data and/or recommend phones and apps that easily provide these data with little additional processing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All systems will drift, and sub-degree is considered very accurate today. If you are trying to track the locations of these animals only with inertial sensors (i.e. without GPS or some other type of geo tag), the accel and gyro sensors in modern cellphones will be dominated by noise after several minutes or 10s of minutes if you're lucky. You likely will need to somehow recalibrate every now and again, with some kind of beacons for triangulation. Most inertial tracking applications today use a combination of step-counting, along with some understanding of the moving body's gait length, in order to track distance traveled, along with WiFi or Bluetooth beacons. Earth's magnetic field can be used for immediate direction orientation. Companies like http://www.tendegrees.net are trying to do this type of thing for indoor navigation and pedestrian dead reckoning.

Comment: Not sure why I got a downvote. Am I not supposed to reference companies? I don't work there, I just know companies are doing this stuff. It's not an ad nor endorsement, just for awareness.

Comment: Thanks Sevron, that was really helpful. What I'm doing is attaching the phone/IMU and camera a tripod throughout survey period. We can then use very basic trigonometry knowing the location of the survey point and angles to the animal to calculate it's location.   Why is it that a  cell phone will drift but an OpenTag will not? I could always turn the phone on and off which would be less than ideal but still doable.  Also, not sure why the down vote. Troll?

Comment: Sorry it's been a long time, not sure if you're still doing this project. I thought you were attaching the sensors to the animals themselves, but as I read this I'm thinking you're not doing that. I don't know what an OpenTag is and can find only software references online. If it contains a GPS receiver then that's why it doesn't drift. GPS is very accurate for X,Y and Z position although it cannot tell orientation (which direction you are facing). Mag sensors are very sensitive to ferrous metals, so keep them away from your mag sensor (use aluminum, not steel/iron).

Comment: Thanks Sevron. I finally gave up after not getting the system within the required tolerances. The survey site was ~1-1.5k from the animals so between the lag in the IMU calculations, slop in the mounting system and time delay between the IMU and the camera it just wasn't going to cut it.

Comment: @KevinJames Was the idea that this would be a sort of a off-the-shelf theodolite?